# How to set Content-Type in s-nail?

Tags: bash, smtp, mailx

I am using [s-nail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/s-nail.1.html) to send emails via SMTP by a bash script. Here is an example:

```
cat data.html | s-nail -v \
 -s "Subject Text" \
 -r "reply@abc.de" \
 -S smtp=smtp.abc.de:587 \
 -S smtp-use-starttls \
 -S smtp-auth=login \
 -S smtp-auth-user="admin@abc.de" \
 -S smtp-auth-password="password1234" \
 -a foo.img \
 foo@bar.com
```

By default the content type is being set to `Text`.

**How to set the `Content-Type` to `html`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late but here you go
`-M "text/html"`